# Filter through a hasMany connection

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `route` and a `destination` model and would like to create a `filteredRoutes` computed property which only contains `routes` which have a `destination.name` with the value of `selectedDestination`. I can't figure out the last puzzle piece to do that. How can I filter that?

**controller.js**

```
filteredRoutes: Ember.computed('model.routes', 'selectedDestination', function() {
    var selectedDestination = this.get('selectedDestination');
    var routes = this.get('model.routes');

    if(selectedDestination) {
      routes = routes.filter(function(route) {
      // ????
      });
    }
  }),
```

**app/destination/model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**app/route/model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  destinations: DS.hasMany('destinations', { async: true })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter`, as you had suggested, with the filter condition being the presence of at least one destination whose name is equal to the selected one.

```
filteredRoutes: Ember.computed(
  'model.routes.@each.destinations.@each.name', 
  'selectedDestination', 

  function() {
    var selectedDestination = this.get('selectedDestination');

    return this.get('model.routes') . filter(
        route =>
          route.get('destinations') . find(
            destination =>
              destination.get('name') === selectedDestination
          )
    );
  }
)
```

In English:

> Find the routes which have at least one destination whose name is the same as the selected destination.